# Проблема с функцией ответа пользователю при использовании reply_markup

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Проблема заключается в следующем:
При использовании `await update.message.reply_text(text="", reply_markup=keyboard)` возникает ошибка

> InlineKeyboardButton.to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

Нашел похожую проблему которой уже год, но на нее так и не поступило ответа.[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823520/openai-completion-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-recursive)

Ошибка возникает на версии *python-telegram-bot>20.0a0*.
Версия *python-telegram-bot-20.0a0* - не вызывает такой ошибки.

Пример кода для демонстрации проблемы:

```
async def fourth_step_notification(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    ONE, TWO = range(2)
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data=str(ONE)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data=str(TWO))
        ]
    ]
    keyword = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    try:
        await update.message.reply_text(text="Hello, python-telegram-bot-20.0a0 :",
                                        reply_markup=keyword)
        return 5

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 4
```

Проблему решила использование python-telegram-bot-20.0a0

Comment: а в чём вопрос? вероятно, вы хотели сделать что-то подобное: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/178576 ? тогда надо сделать чуть иначе - текст ответа убрать из текста вопроса и добавить его как полноценный ответ с помощью соответстующей кнопки.

Comment: Вопрос в существующей проблеме. Официальная документация python-telegram-bot говорит о том, что о существующих проблемах можно сообщать сюда. Таким образом я обращаю внимание разработчиков python-telegram-bot на существующую проблему. 
Нет, я не собирался сделать нечто похожее, а всего-лишь пытался обратить внимание сообщества к этой проблеме

Comment: `Официальная документация python-telegram-bot говорит о том, что о существующих проблемах можно сообщать сюда.` - «сюда», это на **ru**.stackoverflow.com? или всё-таки на англоязычный сайт?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо за то что обратили внимание на мою проблему. Вероятно, вы правы. Надеюсь это поможет и другим пользователям столкнувшимся с аналогичной проблемой.